# Deploying to GCloud VM Instances with GitHub Actions

Tags: continuous-integration, gcloud, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I have a VM instance on GCloud that manages both dev/prod. Currently, I manage deploying by just SSH'ing into the instance, cd'ing into dev/prod, and manually checking out or pulling the new changes.

Trying to automate this process, I can't find any documentation on how to do this with GitHub Actions. It seems like it's expecting me to have two separate instances created for Dev/Prod and then run `gcloud deploy` on it, but hoping there is a simpler way. I can connect to gcloud and run commands, just don't see a way to cd in a specific directory and checkout the relevant branch. Seems like there is an SSH option, but it doesn't seem like it's for this. Any advice would be helpful.

```
      - name: Set up Cloud SDK
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
        with:
          project_id: ${{ secrets.PROJECT_ID }}
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.SA_KEY }}
          export_default_credentials: true
      - name: Update dev branch
        run: |
          gcloud config set project test-project
          gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS
```

Comment: Did you try using the [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) at the beginning of your job steps and then `cd` into your `dev/prod` folder through shell commands like you were doing before?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using appleboy for this with a great deal of success:

https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action